# Php error on <<<_END using xampp

Tags: php, xampp

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo <<<_END 
<pre>
<ul> <li> $row[2] <li> <ul>
</pre>
_END;
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile\home.php on line 64
```

I dont understand what is wrong? The _END: is on the far left with no white spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your code and found out: You have a whitespace after `<<<_END` ;) Remove it and it works.

As a sidenote: You should not use such abstract identifier like `END`, or `STRING`, or such. use identifiers, that *describe* the content, like (in your case) `HTML`. Some IDEs (like PHPStorm) can even highlight code depending the identifier used.

Comment: I cant believe that is even an issue - Ty I will remember that!